# PHP HttpRequest

Tags: php

I need to perform a HTTP GET from PHP.

More specifically, from within /index.php I need to get the content of /trac/ and /svn/, find the "ul" element and then render then inline on the index.php.

/trac and /svn are relative URLs and not filesystem folders.
http://myserver/trac and http://myserver/svn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://myserver/svn/');

// Or, if you don't want to hardcode the server
$str = file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/svn/');

if ($str)
{
    // Find the ul
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at...

- the [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) PEAR Package,
- the [CURL Library](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP (if installed) or
- plain [Filesystem Functions](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) in PHP (if you have [allow_url_fopen](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [file_get_contents](http://it.php.net/function.file-get-contents) - it can be used to open urls under some conditions as can some of the other [filesystem functions](http://it.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php):

> A URL can be used as a filename with
>   this function if the fopen wrappers
>   have been enabled. See fopen() for
>   more details on how to specify the
>   filename and List of Supported
>   Protocols/Wrappers for a list of
>   supported URL protocols.